# Removing identical entries in text documents

Tags: python, file, text

I am trying to come up with a solution for a problem. I have multiple text documents filled with data (very large files, several gigabytes). Each document has a single entry on each line with no spaces. I need to remove entries that occur in more than 1 document. Each entry occurs in each file only once however. I have been able to do this for multiple entries in a single document, but i dont know how to approach the problem for multiple files, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Add all entries to a single set. Sets can't contain duplicates

Comment: @cricket_007 If each file several gigabytes, and it has a few files, you may need terabytes of RAM to create a `set`.  I believe the simplest way to achieve what the Op want is to create a database and let the database handle this. Alternatively concatenate the files into a single file and sort this one using an algorithm that doesn't require the whole contents to be read into RAM (there are specialized algorithms for this; see TAOCP) and then remove consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Does a single file fit into RAM? For example are you able to sort a file by just doing `lines = list(open(file)); lines.sort()` and then save the result?

Comment: Could you include a small example of two files being processed and what you want the output to be?